# Scaling up an animated GIF in python to be used with PyGTK

Tags: python, animation, pygtk, animated-gif

I have this little python script which opens up a window and puts an animated GIF inside the window.  I'm using it as a screensaver (nothing fancy, really).  My problem is that the GIF isn't the size of my monitor; it's quite small on the screen.  What I'd like to do is to scale it to the size of the screen.  I have looked into PIL as well as images2gif, but they don't give me the scaling options I require.

What I would like to do is load the animated GIF in the script, then scale it, and finally play in the window generated by PyGTK.  What I've tried doing is using `subprocess` to capture the output from gifsicle.  While this does scale the GIF I can't use it in the PyGTK part of the script because of the data returned from `subprocess`.  What I do is:

```
p = subprocess.check_output(["gifsicle --scale 3.3 foo.gif"], shell=True)
```

The variable `p` has the animated GIF data, but I can't use with PyGTK in that condition.  Ideally I would like to load it like this:

```
pixbufAn = gtk.gdk.pixbufAnimation(p)
image = gtk.Image()
image.set_from_animation(pixbufAn)
```

Is there a way for me to use the data from the `gifsicle --scale 3.3 foo.gif` call?  Or is there a pure Python way of scaling the animated GIF and using it with PyGTK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logically you can use

```
GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.scale_simple ()
```

on all the GdkPixbuf contains within GdkPixbuf.PixbufAnimation. How to get the single GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf? Use the iter to walk through GdkPixbuf.PixbufAnimation. first iter would be

```
iter = GdkPixbuf.PixbufAnimation.get_iter (GLib.get_current_time() )
pbuf = iter.get_pixbuf ()
# scale the pbuf below
......
# make this on a loop
iter = iter.advance (GLib.get_current_time())

# after getting all the pbuf, pack again into GdkPixbuf.PixbufSimpleAnim
simpleanim = GdkPixbuf.PixbufSimpleAnim (width, height, rate)
# loop again
simpleanim.add_frame (pbuf)

# after done all the chores, call the
Gtk.Image.set_from_animation (simpleanim) #simpleanim implemented anim
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @luciomrx.  To solve this problem what you recommend is getting an iterator from the animation, then using a loop to go through each image of the animation with `pbuf = iter.get_pixbuf()`, and to advance it I would use `iter = iter.advance(glib.get_current_time())` while going through each iteration of the loop?  Then I create an animation with `simpleanim = gtk.gdk.PixbufSimpleAnim(width, height, rate)`, and fill `simpleanim` with `simpleanim.add_frame(pbuf)`?

Comment: yes. PIL would be my first choice actually, but recent of hundreds of experiment with PIL doesn't satisfy me at all.

Comment: This code has sent me in the right direction.  I haven't been able to set up the right screensaver, though.  Thank you for your help, @luciomrx .

Comment: This solution is seducing but has a few flaws. First, `GLib.get_current_time()` returns a float instead of a `GLib.TimeVal`. It can be constructed manually, so not a big deal. Second, I don't see a way to know when you're done iterating on all the frames.